# Candy Crush-like level screen (image with text) Cocos2D

Tags: image, button, text, menu, cocos2d-iphone

The today's doubt is about creating a level starting screen in Cocos2D, where all the levels are shown as a grid with the level's number.
Each level has a pic (maybe a star, or something like that) and the level number. [e.g. Candy Crush main screen]
The question is...
How may I show a pic underneath a number (an String text)? 
Be aware the level should be a MenuItem.

I've thought in the code showed below, but it doesn't fit to my needs (just because I need to overlay the level number as a String)

```
CCMenuItemImage *image1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"image" selectedImage:@"image" target:self selector:@selector(playLevel:)];
                     CCMenuItem *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:image1,image2....imageXX... nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just overlay a CCLabelTTF to the scene on top of the CCmenuitem?

Comment: If I overlay a CCLabalTTF on top of an item, then I can't click on the item, because I will click on the text, and nothing will happen

Comment: What version of cocos2d are you using?  With mine CCmenuitems steal focus even when they are behind other objects.